# C++ Serialization Clean XML Similar to XSTREAM

Tags: c++, xml-serialization, xstream, boost-serialization, codesynthesis

I need to write a linux c++ app which saves it settings in XML format (for easy hand editing) and also communicates with existing apps through XML messages over sockets and HTTP. Problem is that I haven't been able to find any intelligent libs to help me, I don't particular feel like writing DOM or SAX code just to write and read some very simple messages.

Boost Serialization was almost a match, but it adds a lot of boost-specific data to the xml it generates. This obviously doesn't work well for interchange formats. I'm wondering if it is possible to make Boost Serialization or some other c++ serialization library generate clean xml. I don't mind if there are some required extra attributes - like a version attribute, but I'd really like to be able to control their naming and also get rid of 'features' that I don't use - tracking_level and class_id for instance.

Ideally I would just like to have something similar to xstream in Java. I am aware of the fact that c++ lacks introspection and that it is therefore necessary to do some manual coding - but it would be nice if there was a clean solution to just read and write simple XML without kludges!

If this cannot be done I am also interested in tools where the XML schema is the canonical resource (contract first) - a good JAXB alternative to C++. So far I have only found commercial solutions like CodeSynthesis XSD. I would prefer open source solutions. I have tried gSoap - but it generates really ugly code and it is also SOAP-specific.

In desperation I also started looking at alternative serialization formats for protobuffers. This exists - but only for Java! It really surprises me that protocol buffers seems to be a better supported data interchange format than XML.

I'm going mad just finding libs for this app and I really need some new ideas. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what it provides and therefore if it's what you are looking for but Qt has an xml module. It also has a network module which sounds as if it may be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on Troubadour's answer, I've used [Qt's XML libraries](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtxml.html) with great success doing something very close to what you are.  In my own case, I serialize config data to a local file and then occasionally stream it around to other threads.

[QXmlStreamWriter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qxmlstreamwriter.html) and [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qxmlstreamreader.html) are the two classes in question.  [Here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/xml-streambookmarks.html) is an example using them.

For my own XML serialization, I have complete control over the actual format produced and it only took a few hundred lines of code to achieve.  The nicest thing I can say about using Qt's XML is that I could focus on the content and let the libraries do the painful work of marking up the data - which is ideal.

Finally, [here](http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing) is some info on Qt Licenses (Commercial, GPL, LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the question:
*"So far I have only found commercial solutions like CodeSynthesis
XSD. I would prefer open source solutions"*

**CodeSynthesis XSD** can be used by open source projects. The product
has a **Commercial Proprietary License** but in addition to that it
also have an **Open source license** (GPL version 2 but with
additional freedom given). You are allowed to use it together with all
"GPL-Compatible Free Software Licenses" and all "GPL-Incompatible Free
Software Licenses" listed at
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html

The third license option for CodeSynthesis XSD is a **Free Proprietary
License for Small Vocabularies**. You coud use that license for free
if you are using a small XML schema.

Read more about the different CodeSynthesis XSD licenses here:
http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/license.xhtml

In terms of functionality CodeSynthesis XSD also supports serializing
and parsing of a generated binary format. You could use that format
for efficient communication.